# Разбор песни О. Газманова "Офицеры"

Tags: синтаксис

Встретил в Интернете разбор песни Газманова. Автор критикует песню "Офицеры". Цитирую:

...Тем, кто выжил в Афгане,
свою честь не изгадив,
кто карьеры не делал
от солдатских кровей…
Я пою офицерам,
матерей пожалевшим,
возвратив им обратно
живых сыновей...

Оставим на совести педагогов, учивших будущего поэта синтаксису, неуклюжее и двусмысленное сочетание «пожалевшим, возвратив». ***(Когда именно они пожалели: до или после?)***

Вопрос: что хочет сказать критик, говоря "до и после"? Действительно ли здесь двусмыслица? Если да, то какая?

Никак не могу понять мысль автора.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Автор разбора ищет в сочетании глагола с деепричастием последовательность действий: "сделав одно, сделали другое" или "сделали одно, сделав затем другое"? Такое представление свойственно алгоритмическому мышлению программистов. Автор же песни явно ничего во времени не распределял и имел в виду, что *одно действие является проявлением другого* и происходит одновременно с ним: **вернув сыновей, тем самым проявили сочувствие к матерям** (= их пожалели). Не имеет значения, сколько времени это длилось: берегли, испытывая жалось к матерям, стремились, к тому, чтобы вернуть, и в конце концов (результат грамматически выражен формами совершенного вида) вернув, тем самым проявили своё сочувствие: здесь даже пресловутой "поэтической вольности" нельзя усмотреть. Да, есть множество безграмотных и глупых песенных текстов, но на мой взгляд, данный фрагмент - не тот случай.

Comment: Александр, согласен с вами. Здесь два деепричастия совершенного вида. Два последовательных действия. Автор просто придирается.

Comment: @Alex_ander а вы-то, надеюсь, **не согласны** с тем, что "пожалевшим" - деепричастие? ))))

Comment: Это просто оговорка, Серж разбирается и не в таком :)

Comment: Это не просто оговорка (у него). Это позиция. Он не может понять, как делается грамматический разбор - и к чему придрался Юрий Поляков. Хотя Поляков, конечно, то ещё чудо...

Comment: А у вас - другое. Поляков ничего такого не ищет. Он просто боится назвать всё своими именами. Газманов - бездарность как поэт. Или кто ему там тексты пишет. Но грамматика у него правильная.

Comment: Morkovnik, во-первых, мы здесь не обсуждаем Газманова как поэта,  так что давайте воздержимся от субъективной оценки. Во-вторых, грамматический разбор мне делать нечего, в-третьих, повторю: воздержитесь от субъективной оценок. Я прекрасно знаю, что такое грамматический разбор и как его выполняют, а если я не понял мысль Полякова, это еще ничего не значит!

Answer (score 2):

[О ПЕСНЕ ГАЗМАНОВА "ОФИЦЕРЫ" | politklubok.ru](http://politklubok.ru/blog/43382972704/O-pesne-Gazmanova-Ofitseryi)

**Мне разбор песни не нравится — это для начала.**

**А пожалеть до и после можно так:** (1) освободить от воинской службы по какой-либо причине или (2) бережно относиться к солдатским жизням, не бросая своих подчиненных в атаку на верную смерть ради собственной славы, ради выполнения задания любой ценой.

Вообще говоря, это не та тема, где уместно разбирать грамматические ошибки, выявлять художественные достоинства и недостатки. В таких случаях важен дух произведения, его идея, его эмоциональность, **здесь одна удачная фраза может "вытянуть" десяток неудачных других.**

**Есть в жизни народа события, которые лучше воспринимать как миф,** потому что великое и ничтожное в них перемешано так, что трудно отделить одно от другого. Наверное, к таким событиям можно отнести Афганскую войну.

Answer (score 2):

Не люблю Газманова, он косноязычен и заумен, но грамматически в тексте нет никаких ошибок или неточностей. Тут смысл совершенно марсианский, это да. Но не грамматика.

Разбирайте нормально. К чему относится "матерей пожалевшим"? К офицерам. К дополнению.

А к чему относится деепричастие? К глаголу. О какой вообще нестыковке может идти речь?!

Я, ***возвратив сыновей матерям, пою*** [славу] ***офицерам, пожалевшим матерей***.

Смысл, да, заоблачный. Но грамматика соблюдена.

Что касается идеи привязать деепричастие к причастию - да еще согласовывать их по времени, то сей зверь науке неизвестен. Если автор действительно хотел сказать то, что ему тут приписывают, что это офицеры-де возвратили матерям детей, то это вообще ошибка непростительная даже для студента РКИ.

Comment: Я не понял, о чем вы пишете. При чем тут причастие?

Comment: @Серж Причастие - "пожалевшим". Оно при Газманове и при Вашем вопросе: *«Пожалевшим, возвратив»*. Вы говорите о том, что это некое "сочетание", а этого быть не может, вы неверно делаете грамматический разбор. Отсюда и все ваши заморочки.

Comment: Morkovkin, разбор делаю не я, я пытался понять, к чему придиряется автор.

Comment: @Серж Так сделайте сами, если умеете. Грамматический разбор, а не литературно-художественный. Хотя после тезиса о двух деепричатсиях оно как и обидно.  И оформляйте цитаты как положено. Не оформили - всё вопросы к вам.

Comment: Morkovkin, формально Вы правы: по строгим правилам деепричастие должно относится к глаголу и фраза означает, что автор поет, возвратив сыновей. Конечно, Газманов имел ввиду не это, и все сразу понимают этот текст именно так, как хотел автор. А раз все понятно - так может простим автору эту поэтическую вольность? Вот, например, статья, в которой говорится: "Поэтический текст является для авторов полем для экспериментов с деепричастными оборотами" (http://rusgram.ru/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5#14)

Comment: @М_Г  *Газманов имел ввиду не это* - Давайте не будем за всех решать. Мы тут русским языком занимаемся, а не теориями массового сознания. В любом случае, даже если вы и правы, это даёт исчерпывающий ответ, что не неправильно во фразе и/или что людям в ней не нравится... Прощать косноязычие я автору не собираюсь. Поляков прав, хотя и сам нагородил такого, что хоть святых выноси.